# Calibrate Accelerometer?

Tags: ios, accelerometer, uiaccelerometer

I see many apps on the app store that have a button like calibrate accelerometer (for example: Doodle Jump)

I am looking to implement a similar way to calibrate the accelerometer in my app.

I am using the default UIAccelerometer API's and stuff like that but I just want to account say if the user is playing on their side etc...

How would I go upon doing this?

Thanks,
Brad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apps that "calibrate" the accelerometer aren't really changing the values that the accelerometer returns, they're just taking readings with the device in a known state that they can then use to adjust data that they read in the future. If you place the device on a table, for example, and take a reading, and then you turn the device 180° and take another reading, you know that the device's error must be half the difference between those two readings. You can then adjust any future readings by that error to get more accurate results.